# Aiogram send message without handler and use existing bot

Tags: python, async-await, aiogram

When using a bot, there is a need to send(edit) a message at an arbitrary point(separate function send_msg_without_hendler(message)). Roughly speaking, as the message from open AI is updated, the bot must send message and then update this message.
When calling the send_msg_without_hendler(msg) function, how can you use a already-made "Bot" object instead of creating a new one? As if we needs to push a message into the queue

main.py:

```
async def aiogram_bot():
    bot = Bot(token=BOT_TOKEN, parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
    dp = Dispatcher(storage=MemoryStorage())
    dp.include_router(router)
    await bot.delete_webhook(drop_pending_updates=True)
    await dp.start_polling(bot, allowed_updates=dp.resolve_used_update_types())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if server_mode=="PROD":
        asyncio.run(aiogram_bot())
```

handler.py:

```
async def send_msg_without_handler(message):
   # every time new bot, but i want use existing
    client = TelegramClient('.venv/session_name', telethon_api_id, telethon_api_hash) 

    send_message = await client.send_message(chat_id, message)
    id_send_message = send_message.to_dict()["id"]
```

trying to send message by:

```
await send_msg_without_handler('messageText')
```